# Argument type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to loop through an object by doing:

```
  const db = admin.firestore()
  const devicesRef = db.collection('devices')
  const devices = await devicesRef.get();
  devices.forEach(async (result, idx, array) => {

  });
```

But I get an error:

> Argument of type '(result: any, idx: any, array: any) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(result: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => void'.

Which I don't really understand. If I get rid of `idx, array` the script works perfectly, but I want to know when the last loop is being performed, which is why I add `idx, array`...

Any ideas what the error messages might mean?

Comment: Apparently the `devices.forEach` is **not** the standard `Array.prototype.forEach`. What does `devicesRef.get` return?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it returns a list of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `devices` is an array of objects, I don't think you can assign your function there as the function only expects one argument which will get individual device. Try:

```
  const db = admin.firestore()
  const devicesRef = db.collection('devices')
  const result = await devicesRef.get();

  // adds all results to devices list
  List<any> devices = [];
  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot device : result.getResult()) {
    devices.add(device);
  }

  devices.forEach((device idx, array) => {
    if (idx === array.length -1) {
       // Do specific task
    }
    // some async function
    async (someOtherFunction) => {
       // do something with individual device
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. In this implementation will `array` actually return an array? As my objective is to know when I'm at the end of the loop using `if (idx === array.length - 1) {`

Comment: if you need index, you can still do your way, but remove async at forEach and do it later inside the function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I still get the same error :( `Argument of type '(result: any, idx: any, array: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(result: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => void'.`

Comment: Looks like, you are getting QueryDocumentSnapshot not a list or array. So, you will have to convert it to a list. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035752/how-to-get-list-of-documents-from-a-collection-in-firestore-android)

Comment: Thank you. I actually realized I can do `devices.size` and just keep a counter in the loop :)

Comment: You can do that too! I still edited my answer for when you need a list out.